# audio quality issue on fedora linux: triggered randomly or by unplugging charger during wine games

Tags: fedora, audio, wine, troubleshooting, pipewire

So after a recent fedora update (the ones that require a reboot) lutris wine games have been acting up lately, audio suddenly becomes 8-bit-like and super low quality, and sometimes by chance it goes back to normal. Heres what i think is causing it:

1. Unplugging laptop charger triggers the issue somehow only while in-game
2. For some odd reason, if i play music in the background with a player e.g. lolypop, the audio stays normal until the music stops
3. All wine-ge versions have this issue now, i reinstalled all my systems packages out of desperation, disabled all my gnome extensions, tried running the games (all wine games have this issue) but the issue still exists.

Some temporary fixes i found were restarting the pipewire services, but then i have close and re-open the game but then issue kicks in again.

`journalctl -xe | pipewire` gave nothing, same for `journalctl -xe | pulse`

`systemctl --user status pipewire` gave no errors too

Here's my neofetch if that helps:

```
------------------
OS: Fedora Linux 38 (Workstation Edition) x86_64
Host: HP Laptop 15-dw3xxx
Kernel: 6.4.11-200.fc38.x86_64
Uptime: 1 hour, 32 mins
Packages: 3246 (rpm), 75 (flatpak)
Shell: bash 5.2.15
Resolution: 1366x768
DE: GNOME 44.3
WM: Mutter
WM Theme: MaterialYou
Theme: adw-gtk3-dark [GTK2/3]
Icons: Adwaita [GTK2/3]
Terminal: gnome-terminal
CPU: 11th Gen Intel i5-1135G7 (8) @ 4.200GHz
GPU: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce MX350
Memory: 3767MiB / 7667MiB
```

I have long recordings of the issue if that helps. Im confident this isnt a firmware/drivers issue since most if not all of my drivers work perfectly on my laptop.

I really want to send a bug report if there's no fix for this but I don't know what logs point to this issue.

Additional info:

-Audio hardware: `0000:00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)`

-Pipewire version: `Compiled with libpipewire 0.3.78 Linked with libpipewire 0.3.78`

-Wine version: Wine-GE-Proton8-14

-Gnome Extensions: `Vitals@CoreCoding.com openweather-extension@jenslody.de caffeine@patapon.info just-perfection-desktop@just-perfection user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io clipboard-indicator@tudmotu.com x11gestures@joseexposito.github.io quick-settings-audio-panel@rayzeq.github.io oneclickbios@sao.studio quick-settings-avatar@d-go search-light@icedman.github.com tiling-assistant@leleat-on-github blur-my-shell@aunetx scroll-workspaces@gfxmonk.net improvedosk@nick-shmyrev.dev widgets@aylur allowlockedremotedesktop@kamens.us material-you-theme@asubbiah.com BingWallpaper@ineffable-gmail.com draw-on-your-screen2@zhrexl.github.com EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com background-logo@fedorahosted.org appindicatorsupport@rgcjonas.gmail.com`

Thanks!